# Google Chrome v.75, Google Canary v.78 crashes when open dev tools with disabled chrome://flags "Disable site isolation"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-canary

Google Chrome v.75
Google Canary v.78
chrome://flags "#site-isolation-trial-opt-out" - disabled
So the problem is that browser crashes right after attempt to open developer tools with changed flag.

I tried to switch between original chrome version to canary but catch up the same problem

I expected the developer tools working with changed any of chrome://flags

Comment: Not sure how you want the StackOverflow community to help you with an answer here, I don't see an actual question. If you want to open an issue on Chromium's bug tracker, it's there: https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/?token=5VKw3mc0wOBSPe9mcMLEQzoxNTY0NjYwMjAw&role=&continue=https%3A//bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.do

Comment: so I went to Chromium's bug tracker via link which Kalido suggested. Full-filled all form and press submit. It redirects to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.do with 400 error or if go here straight it loads with message "The page you asked for does not exist."

Comment: Hmm maybe this link is not shareable sorry. But from https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.do you have a "new issue" button at top; Click it and fill the form.